# Need To Get The Status of Each Iteration in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Need To Get The Status of Each Iteration in UFT like Execution Status, Error Message if the that particular iteration is failed and the status of Checkpoint. Whether it is pass or failed. I have checked for one code which i got from another forum but cannot be self explanatory. Can anyone help in getting more clear on the option to get the status of each iteration.

Code:

```
List<IterationStatus> iterationList = this.Context.ExecutionStatus.IterationStatus;

if (iterationList.Count > 0)
{
  this.Context.UserLogger.Info(iterationList[1].CheckpointFailed.ToString());
  this.Context.UserLogger.Info(iterationList[1].Succeed.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The code that you have is CustomCode from UFT API, which is written in C#.

Comment: Yes. We have written the code in C# for API testing. We need to get the status, error message and to get the complete information which we are getting in the default ALM report. By using those information, we will create our customized report in HTML and Excel format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the result of the code that you have right now? Do you have the output available for our review?

Comment: I didnt get any code related to extracting the report information from UFT. It would be helpful if i get the same. I have checked across google. But i didnt get any information. The code which i got has been provided in the question.